# How can I use the LoginManager class from FacebookSDK inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

It looks like the LoginManager from the FacebookSDK contains a method only with an android.support.v4.app.Fragment parameter, and none with android.app.Fragment. Unfortunately, v4.app.Fragment is not an option for me. I have tried doing the same thing in an Activity and in an v4.app.Fragment, and it works. However, I cannot use either of those.

```
private void init() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    onLoginSuccess(loginResult);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    onLogInFailed();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    onLogInFailed();
                }
            });
}

private void logIn() {
    Global.log("logging in to facebook");
    Collection<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), permissions);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The method in question is loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions, that can take either an activity or a v4.app.Fragment as a parameter, but not the type of Fragment i need.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermission() takes either Activity or Fragment parameters. It doesn't matter whater it's v4.app.Fragment or app.Fragment.

Comment: I tried giving a simple Fragment as a paramater, but I cannot. I looked at the implementation of the method and it only accepts v4.app.Fragment. The LoginManager class has no mentioning of the plain Fragment class anywhere

Comment: The SDK only supports v4.app.Fragment since we support back to Gingerbread (and android.app.Fragment wasn't introduced until Honeycomb). You need to either just use v4.app.Fragment, or fork and modify the SDK and replace all instances of v4.app.Fragment with android.app.Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It was implemented in the Facebook SDK version 4.8.0 (Nov 11, 2015), take a look:

> Added support for using login manager and UI elements with native
>   fragments (android.app.Fragment)

And the documentation has been updated as well:

> **CallbackManager** - Use to route calls back to the Facebook SDK and your
>   registered callbacks. You should call it from the initiating activity
>   or fragments onActivityResult call.

Sources:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x#4_8_0